# undefined method `each_with_index' for model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

```
class Account
  has_many :account_configs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_configs
end

class AccountConfig
  belongs_to :account
end
```

**controller**

```
def show
end


def new
  @account = Account.new
  @account_config = @account.account_configs.build
end

def create
  @account = Account.new(account_params)
  if @account.save
    redirect_to account_path(@account), notice: 'Account was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:name, account_configs_attributes: [:id, :type, :duration, :branch]) if params[:account]
end
```

After creating the model `Account` with its config in a nested form I should show it in `show` page. I need to loop over this `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` - `@account.account_configs`. There is also a `layout_builder` file previously written. I need to extend the same layout for this page also. When I try to loop like this

```
@account.account_configs.each do |config|
  #here extending from the layout which has other check methods
end
```

I am getting this error: `undefined method each_with_index for #<AccountConfig:0----->`.

But instead of `each` if I use `where` on the same, the layout is extended and rendered. I can use `where` but a lot of code is repeated. What should I do to make make this error go away in this case?

**error_log**

```
D, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.851681 #25672] DEBUG -- :   Account Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  `accounts`.* FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
D, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.863820 #25672] DEBUG -- :   AccountConfig Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  `account_config`.* FROM `account_config` WHERE `account_config`.`account_id` = 5  ORDER BY `account_config`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.874536 #25672] DEBUG -- :   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `account_config`.* FROM `account_config` WHERE `account_config`.`account_id` = 5  ORDER BY `account_config`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["account_id", 5]]
D, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.887123 #25672] DEBUG -- :   Account Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `accounts`.`id`, `accounts`.`name` FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`account_id` = 5
D, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.896571 #25672] DEBUG -- :   AccountConfig Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  `account_config`.* FROM `account_config` WHERE `account_config`.`account_id` = 5  ORDER BY `account_config`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
I, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.922217 #25672]  INFO -- :   Rendered customer/accounts/show.html.erb within layouts/customer (62.6ms)
I, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.930145 #25672]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 101ms (ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)
F, [2019-07-24T14:06:35.960592 #25672] FATAL -- : 
NoMethodError - undefined method `each_with_index' for #<AccountConfig:0x00005581ed35b6e0>:
  lib/layout_builder.rb:693:in `records'
  app/views/customer/accounts/show.html.erb:37:in `block (4 levels) in _app_views_customer_accounts_show_html_erb___136536495548701304_47008262570920'
  lib/layout_builder.rb:641:in `initialize'
  lib/layout_builder.rb:216:in `record_list'
  app/views/customer/accounts/show.html.erb:33:in `block (3 levels) in _app_views_customer_accounts_show_html_erb___136536495548701304_47008262570920'
  app/views/customer/accounts/show.html.erb:31:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_customer_accounts_show_html_erb___136536495548701304_47008262570920'
  lib/layout_builder.rb:162:in `block in article'
  lib/layout_builder.rb:281:in `level'
  lib/layout_builder.rb:160:in `article'
  app/views/customer/accounts/show.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_customer_accounts_show_html_erb___136536495548701304_47008262570920'
  lib/layout_builder.rb:153:in `page'
  app/views/customer/accounts/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_customer_accounts_show_html_erb___136536495548701304_47008262570920'

D, [2019-07-24T14:06:36.118610 #25672] DEBUG -- : 
D, [2019-07-24T14:06:36.118734 #25672] DEBUG -- : 
I, [2019-07-24T14:06:36.118873 #25672]  INFO -- : Started POST "/__better_errors/60b69c8a4bd7e26b/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-24 14:06:36 +0530
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% configs = @account.account_configs %>    

<% configs.each do |config| %>
<div class="custom-class"><h2><%= "#{config.type}" %></h2></div>

  <% a.record_list configs do |rl| %>
    <% rl.header 'duration' %>
    <% rl.header 'branch' %>
    <% rl.records do |data| %>
      <% if data.type == "#{config.type}" %>
        <% rl.show data.duration %>
        <% rl.show data.branch %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you share controller code as well?

Comment: Can you add detail error message?

Comment: @sreangrathanak That is the error message that I got in browser. Should I share what is in the log?

Comment: @Laxman it better to have information.

Comment: Does account_params accepts account_configs parameters?
You should also check whether account_configs are present for the account?, If yes then only you should iterate on the same.

Comment: @KrupaSuthar Yes. It accepts and it is created from the `create` page. The problem is in the `show` page.

Comment: For the same account, Are you able to use each_with_index in rails console?

Comment: @KrupaSuthar No. I am not able to use.

Comment: Then there must be some problem with models only, Can you share exact code that your models have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@account.account_configs.each do |config|` will loop to provide you each `AccountConfig` single object in form of block variable `config` on which you have called `each_with_index`

`each_with_index` is only supported for `collection/enumerable` object and not a single object `AccountConfig`.

I had same error when I called that method on `User` object,

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_with_index' for #<User:0x00000007128c00>
```

Inspect following for `each_with_index`,

```
lib/layout_builder.rb:216:in `record_list'
lib/layout_builder.rb:693:in `records'
```

**Solution**-

You can work around by passing object `config` as `[config]` which will act as enumerable object

Comment: Yes. I read it. So is there a way to change it to `enumerable`? Or should I use `where`?

Comment: @Laxman object `user` can be enumerable if I show it as `[user]` but I need to check code at that place to provide better alternative, just provided  clarification to your error.

Comment: My present code works but I am still looping over `configs` and not `config`. So can I better the present code?

Comment: Yes. The reason you gave above is the actual reason because the `record_list` method contains `each_with_index` and was expecting an `enumerable` whereas I was sending a single object  and `[config]` worked for me. So please add your comment to the answer. I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: @Laxman yup, did. But check other cases where these changes will not harm :)

Comment: Sure. I will check. :)

Answer (score 0):

we cannot use each_with_index on an single object, it works on active record collection. If you need index of account_configs objects inside the current loop. Try with this loop.

```
@account.account_configs.each_with_index do |config, index|
  # index - will give the current loop count.
end
```

Comment: Issue is inside `lib/layout_builder.rb` which is getting called through `record_list`. He did not post that code well.